# How to plot a graph with group by?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a dataframe like this:

```
quantity    fruit
---------------------
1           apple
1           apple
0           apple
1           orange
```

I want to `group by` all *fruits* and plot graph for total percentage which has quantity 1.
For example, *apple* will have 2/3 = 66.67% and *orange* will have 1/3 = 33.33%

So, I want to plot a graph with *fruit* on the x-axis and % on the y-axis.

Comment: how is apple 2/3 = 66%? and orange 100%? you have 7/8 apples and 1/8 oranges. is your question right? please confirm.

Comment: @robinhoodjr I made the change. Thanks.

Comment: John, that makes it clearer...just posted my answer. Check it out.

Comment: John, did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this and get the desired result you wanted. Check this out.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

res = df.groupby(['fruit']).sum()
res['percentage'] = res['quantity'] / res['quantity'].sum() # add * 100 for percentage
print(res)
ax = res['percentage'].plot(kind='bar', title ="Your Demo Graph", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Fruits", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Percentage", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
pd.concat([dataframe, colum-you-want-to-group-by], axis=1).groupby('name-of the-column').name-of-the-column.mean().plot(kind='barh').set_xlabel('% TEXT')
```

The above is correct if you have splitted your column from the dataframe, if you didn't just omit the `concat` like this:

```
name-of-your-dataframe.groupby('name-of the-column').name-of-the-column.mean().plot(kind='barh').set_xlabel('% TEXT')
```